# Condtitions in void functions

Tags: c, function, if-statement, recursion, printf

Can someone please explain to me why in the following code, after it prints out 1 consecutively , the value for a increases again? Shouldn't it stop there, after the second 1?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void f(int a)
{
    printf ("%d\n",a*a);
    if (a>1)
        f(a-1);
    printf ("%d ",a*a);
}
int main()
{
    f(5);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
25
16
9
4
1
1 4 9 16 25
```

Comment: Please show what output you get.

Comment: The *value of a* never actually increases. How could it? You're just seeing the execution of the final `printf` call in the 'rewind' of the already made recursive calls to your function.

Comment: You print twice per function call. Once before calling recursively and once afterwards.

Comment: It prints the squares on the way *in* the recursion, and again on the way *out* (but without newlines).

Comment: The output is:
25
16
9
4
1
1 4 9 16 25

Comment: This is actually a very nice, simple function for showing how recursion works. If you were to ask me, "How does recursion work?" I would likely present a function similar to this to show you.

Comment: That is one number per `printf`. Each value is printed twice. When dealing with recursion you need to remember that there is not only a "way down" till the end of recursion but also the "way back up". That is a great example when you should grab your debugger and check where program execution comes along and what values your variables have at each call to `f`

Comment: Try to read about how recursion works.

Comment: Do you *want* it to stop after the second `1`? That can be achieved with a simple modification...

Answer (score 1):

Each recursively called function prints the passed value multiplied by itself two times

```
void f(int a)
{
    printf ("%d\n",a*a);
    //... 
    printf ("%d ",a*a);
}
```

In the last recursive call the value of a is not greater than 1. So the function outputs (I do not take into account the difference in the calls of `printf` relative to the new line character `'\n'`)

```
25  <- first call
   16  <- second call
      9  <- third call
         4  <- forth call
            1  <- fifth call
            1  <- fifth call
         4  <- forth call
      9  <- third call
   16  <- second call
25  <- first call
```

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you're printing twice. Just need once. Test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
    void f(int a) {
        printf ("%d\n",a*a);
        if(a>1)
            f(a-1);
    } 
   int main() {   
        f(5); 
        return 0;
   }
```

The output is now:

```
25
16
9
4
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are presenting a really nice example of recursion.

What is happening here is that the first print, the one at the top of the function is printing the first sets os a*a, while the final print comes from the end of the recursion, let's say, when the recursion is done is printing in its way out.

Printouts before the recursion calls.

```
25
16
9
4
1

1 4 9 16 25 -> line from recursion.
```